# MYSQL/PHP: Concat returning to many fields on LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

I had a `SELECT` query with a `LEFT JOIN` working as desired.  I then added one more table via a smilar `LEFT JOIN` and now I am getting a wierd result.  Basically, for a `group_concat` where I was getting one item for every record, I am getting eight records.  I don't see why this is happening because the join to the new table is analagous to several other joins that do not have this problem (that I have omitted from the example for clarity).

Here is the query that is fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.*, 
group_concat(tf.todoid) as `tftodoid`, 
group_concat(tf.id) as `tfid`, 
group_concat(tf.filedescript) as `tffiledescript`, 
group_concat(tf.filename) as `tffilename`, 
group_concat(tf.founderid) as `tffounderid`, 
group_concat(tf.ext) as `tfext`, 
group_concat(tf.lasttouched) as `tilt`
FROM titles `t`
LEFT JOIN titlefiles `tf` 
ON (tf.todoid = t.id AND tf.founderid = '$userid') 
WHERE t.userid='$userid' 
GROUP BY t.id";
```

And here is the query with the extra join that is now spilling out the multiple copies of the items:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.*, 
group_concat(tf.todoid) as `tftodoid`, 
group_concat(tf.id) as `tfid`, 
group_concat(tf.filedescript) as `tffiledescript`, 
group_concat(tf.filename) as `tffilename`, 
group_concat(tf.founderid) as `tffounderid`, 
group_concat(tf.ext) as `tfext`, 
group_concat(tf.lasttouched) as `tilt`, 
group_concat(s.id) as `stepid`, 
group_concat(s.step) as `steps` 
FROM titles `t`
LEFT JOIN titlefiles `tf` 
ON (tf.titleid = t.id AND tf.founderid = '$userid') 
LEFT JOIN steps `s` 
ON s.titleid = t.id 
WHERE t.userid='$userid' 
GROUP BY t.id";
```

Here is an example of output in JSON showing the difference:

First query:

```
"tfid":"56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81"
```

Second query:

```
"tfid":"56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,75,76,81",
```

I suspect the problem has something to do with the JOIN or with the Group By statements but I can't see how to fix.

How can I ensure that I get only one fileid per file as opposed to eight?

Answer (score 1):

Alter the line as follows:

```
group_concat(DISTINCT tf.id) as `tfid`,
```

This then only gets you the unique ids.
If you want them ordered add:

```
group_concat(DISTINCT tf.id ORDER BY tf.id ASC) as `tfid`,
```

Comment: Does this DISTINCT delete dupes as in if you have two with same number on purpose?

Comment: I found out it does delete.  This would be a good solution except I need to preserve dupes.  For example, there could be multiple file extensions of jpg.

Comment: It looks like a subquery may be needed as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135